# Flashcard toss a coin dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I'm trying to print keys or values in random order from the dictionary.
(Randomly whether to show the entry first or the corresponding definition.)

But I'm getting only a key first followed by a value.
What am I missing for the code to work?

Example:

- Test-1 (Pressing Return Key) Definition-1
- Definition-4 (Pressing Return Key) Test-4
- Definition-2 (Pressing Return Key) Test-2
- Test-3(Pressing Return Key) Definition-3 ...

```
 from random import *
    
    def flashcard():
        random_key = choice(list(dictionary))
        print('Define: ', random_key)
        input('Press return to see the definition')
        print(dictionary[random_key])
    
    dictionary = {'Test-1':'Definition-1',
                'Test-2':'Definition-2',
                'Test-3':'Definition-3',
                'Test-4':'Definition-4'}
    
    exit = False while not exit:
        user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard and q to quit: ')
        if user_input == 'q':
            exit = True
        elif user_input == 's':
            flashcard()
        else:
            print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```

Comment: your example is what youd like your output to look like or what it looks like now?

Comment: What i would like to look like, I've tried random, choice I've tried to swap that around but cant get that to work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can choose a random int between 0 and 1 or you can choose between 0 and 1.

```py
def flashcard():
    k, v = choice(list(dictionary.items()))
    # toss a coin to decide whether to show the key or the value
    # alternative is randint(0, 1)
    if choice((True, False)):
        print('Define: ', k)
        input('Press return to see the definition')
        print(v)
    else:
        print('What is: ', v)
        input('Press return to see the key')
        print(k)
```

Comment: I like this, easy to follow and give them the option of retrieving the key using the value

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.random` to determine whether random_key  or definition should be shown first

```py
from random import *


def flashcard():
    random_key = choice(list(dictionary))
    if random() > 0.5:
        print("Define: ", random_key)
        input("Press return to see the definition")
        print(dictionary[random_key])
    else:
        print("Define: ", dictionary[random_key])
        input("Press return to see the key")
        print(random_key)


dictionary = {
    "Test-1": "Definition-1",
    "Test-2": "Definition-2",
    "Test-3": "Definition-3",
    "Test-4": "Definition-4",
}

exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input("Enter s to show a flashcard and q to quit: ")
    if user_input == "q":
        exit = True
    elif user_input == "s":
        flashcard()
    else:
        print("You need to enter either q or s.")
```

Answer (score 0):

another option is using `sample` (learn [more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)):

```
from random import choice,sample

def flashcard():
    print('Define: {}\nThe key: {}'.format(*sample(choice([*dictionary.items()]),2)))

dictionary = {'Test-1':'Definition-1',
            'Test-2':'Definition-2',
            'Test-3':'Definition-3',
            'Test-4':'Definition-4'}

# testing
for _ in range(3):
    flashcard()
    print()

>>> out
'''
Define: Test-4
The key: Definition-4

Define: Definition-1
The key: Test-1

Define: Definition-2
The key: Test-2
```